# SSH Server in Cygwin - Windows 7

Tags: ssh, cygwin, openssh

I created a ssh server in cygwin using the commands:

```
mkpasswd -l /etc/passwd
mkgroup -l /etc/group
ssh-host-config -y
```

After that, I'm trying to connect the server but it closes my connection with the following message:

```
$ ssh cyg_server@localhost
cyg_server@localhost's password:
Last login: Thu Jul 18 16:16:53 2013 from ::1
Connection to localhost closed.
```

Why it is happening? How do I fix it?

Note: Firewall - off

Thanks =)

Comment: How are you connecting the server?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have permission to connect in the machine that you've created the server?

Comment: I'm not sure, what is the correctly way to do define my permission?